# Selenium webdriver on Live server

Tags: selenium

I need to use php-selenium in remote or in web hosting

Is there any free service like http://www.browserstack.com/automate/php

```
 $web_driver = RemoteWebDriver::create("http://USERNAME:ACCESS_KEY@hub.browserstack.com/wd/hub", 
      array("platform"=>"WINDOWS", "browserName"=>"firefox"));
```

which allowed to create live/remote web driver. or selenium provide any solution for this to run on live server.

Comment: do you find any solution to it?